# Selenium. Python. Chrome. How to get current (active/focused) tab?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tabs, chromium

Ubuntu + Python3 + Selenium + Chromium

I'm using selenium in semi-automated tests. Some work doing user, and some work are automated by python. And i have a problem. I want to know which tab active right now? User can change tabs - and script should work with active tab only. I find lot of answers how to open a tabs and "switch to" - but all of that is not a for me. I don't want to switch to some tab. I want to know what a active tab right now.

- I have a opened browser with lot of pages.
- User can interact with that. He can change tabs and open/close anything
- Than User go back to "App window" (interface of app but not a chrome) and click button
- App execute a function that interact with current (active/focused) page in Chrome

To do that i need to know what a page is active right now. Not active in Selenium but current/active/focused in Chrome. I need to get current/active/focused tab in Chrome.

ps. I don't know what it's called exactly. That's why I write: current/active/focused. For me this is the current tab in the browser, but perhaps this is the wrong name for Chrome.

Comment: okey, if you detect whether the user has manually switched tags, I think you should do this: when the program is running in a place where many tags have been opened, record the currently active tags first, then manually switch tags, and make a loop to detect the current active ones. Is the tag changed? If it changes, switch to it and execute the corresponding code. Is this feasible?

Comment: yes. its working. But i have 2 problems: 1) script can't do anything in stealth mode. for example i don't want to go back to app to press a button. i want to run script that monitoring where exactly i browsing and do some actions without my command. 2) if i have a 2 tabs with same pages - script can't handle where exactly he should work.

Comment: You could possibly use the visibility api for this.  When you need to know which tab is in front, you'd switch through all tabs and check visibility api by executing script and checking Document.visibilityState:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API  I suppose this will only work if switching the driver to the tab doesn't bring it to the front (I don't think it will until maybe a certain action is taken like a click or sending keys)

Comment: my script running every second and switching tabs. user cant work - he just watching how all pages are switching and switching. I need solution to "silent/stealth" script working. When script switching tabs - user cant work... And i tried to switch tabs and asked visibility - browser says True for all pages because i switched to tab already... This can help only to know state for current page. If user go to another page - current page says False. But if i switch to any page - that page becomes active

Comment: If switching the driver to another tab/window brings it to front, I think you'll need to find another way... possibly through a browser plugin/extension.  You could poll to get all windows handles and keep track of those, but you will never know which tab the user is currently working in.  Tabs/windows are isolated/separate processes.  You could possibly inject messaging/listener for certain things, though:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I created already simple browser extension that read state of all tabs and send that data to my RestAPI server. That data contains a tab number and state but i cant combine it with selenium tabs. If user move tabs - extension data will be changed but selenium data not. Selenium return tabs ordered by creation. Im thinking that i should leave a selenium and create all that functionality in browser extension only with my RestAPI for data delivery to both side. That is a bad way for me because javascript is not my primary language